# ffmpeg img to video = Could find no file with path

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

i try to convert img to mp4 with ffmpeg. i try to do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -f image2 -start_number 1 -i '/tmp/stream/_%09d.jpg' -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

and get an error:

```
[image2 @ 0xe74800] Could find no file with path '/tmp/stream/_%09d.jpg' and index in the range 1-5
/tmp/stream/_%09d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

The jpg file-name format is:

```
/tmp/stream/2017_11_20_08_48_30_picture_000000001.jpg
/tmp/stream/2017_11_20_08_48_35_picture_000000002.jpg
/tmp/stream/2017_11_20_08_48_40_picture_000000003.jpg
***
/tmp/stream/2017_11_20_08_56_30_picture_000000999.jpg
```

anyone can help, where is mistake?... Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To match **all** jpg files in `/tmp/stream` use:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg'
```

For more specificity use additional glob patterns. For example, if you only want images from 2017-11-08 to 2017-11-10:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i '/tmp/stream/2017_11_{08,09,10}*.jpg'
```

For more info on glob patterns see `man 7 glob`.

Answer (score -1):

`_%09d.jpg` matches names of the form `_000000001.jpg`, `_000000002.jpg`

Use `-pattern_type glob -i '/tmp/stream/*_%09d.jpg'`

Comment: it's impossible, "08_48_30" it's a time then it's different for  different files....

Comment: Update your example names to reflect that, and try my edited answer.

Comment: now i use: 
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -f image2 -start_number 1 -pattern_type glob -i '/tmp/stream/*_%09d.jpg' -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4 and get: 
[image2 @ 0xf33800] Could not open file : /tmp/stream/*_%09d.jpg

Comment: Don't have a linux setup to test, but change to double quotes and check.

Comment: Directed to another user.

Comment: What are your image filenames?